# Flutter Dio test url endpoint path

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, flutter-test, dio

Here's how I fetch data from an endpoint:

```dart
  @override
  Future<Points> getPoints({required int id}) async {
    try {
      Response pointsResponse = await dio.get(
        "points/$id/",
      );

      return Points.fromJson(pointsResponse.data);
    } on DioError catch (dioError) {
      throw ServerException(dioError.message);
    }
  }
```

Now as a part of my test, I want to test that calling `getPoints(id: 12)` would make a `get` call on `dio` and hit this endpoint: `points/12/`.

Sample test:

```dart
  test(
    "should return Points for a valid id",
    () async {
      when(mockDioAdapter.fetch(any, any, any)).thenAnswer(
        (_) async => successfulRequestResponseJson,
      );

      Points points = await pointsRemoteDataSource.getPoints(id: 12);

      // Want to assert something like: 
      // verify(dio.request.path, "/points/12");
    },
  );
```